# Filter stop words in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am attempting to filter out the stop words out of an RDD of words from a `.txt` file.

```
// Creating the RDDs
val input = sc.textFile("../book.txt")
val stopWordsInput = sc.textFile("../stopwords.csv")
val stopWords = stopWordsInput.map(x => x.split(","))

// Create a tuple of test words
val testWords = ("you", "to")

// Split using a regular expression that extracts words
val wordsWithStopWords = input.flatMap(x => x.split("\\W+"))
```

The code above all makes sense to me and seems to work fine.  This is where I'm having trouble.

```
//Remove the stop words from the list
val words = wordsWithStopWords.filter(x => x != testWords)
```

This will run but doesn't actually filter out the words contained in the tuple `testWords`.  I'm not sure how to test the words in `wordsWithStopWords` against every word in my tuple `testWords`

Comment: I don't see the usage of testWords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing a String over a a tuple `("you", "to")`, which will always be false.

Here is what you want to try:

```
val testWords = Set("you", "to")
wordsWithStopWords.filter(!testWords.contains(_))

// Simulating the RDD with a List (works the same with RDD)
List("hello", "to", "yes") filter (!testWords.contains(_))
// res30: List[String] = List(hello, yes)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Theres an error with both `!` and `.contains`.

Comment: I like this! :-) You can also write it like this: `wordsWithStopWords filterNot testWords`.

Comment: Because you have a tuple as `testWords` which I don't think is realistic. You will have either a list or a set as stop words, at least that is what you should have based on your code.

Comment: @JakeHenningsgaard The answer has been changed slightly (notice the `Set` method being called on the first line of the snippet), perhaps you can try it again. In case you are coming from Python, please note that Scala has a very different concept of tuples.

Comment: `Set` works, but now I have a follow-on question.  `testWords` was used obviously just to test out the filter function.  I now want to replace it with the following `val words = wordsWithStopWords.filter(!stopWords.contains(_))'.  This does not work, I'm assuming because its `stopWords' is not a `Set`.  So, my question is, when I declare `stopWords` and use `.map` to `split` the `csv` values, what is that datastructure?  Tuple, Array, List?

Comment: @stefanobaghino spark doesn't implement `filterNot`.

Comment: `stopWords` is usually a small set, I don't think you need to distribute it. Just collect it as a Set. `val stopWords = stopWords.collect().toSet` before doing this.

Comment: Let's say that it's safer to use a broadcast variable instead of collect even if this is a plausible solution.

Comment: It depends on how your file looks like, it looks to me you are going to have `List[List[String]]`, as you are doing `.map(_.split(","))`, you might want a `flatMap` here too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Broadcast variable to filter with your stopwords RDD :

```
// Creating the RDDs
val input = sc.textFile("../book.txt")
val stopWordsInput = sc.textFile("../stopwords.csv")

// Flatten, collect, and broadcast.
val stopWords = stopWordsInput.flatMap(x => x.split(",")).map(_.trim)
val broadcastStopWords = sc.broadcast(stopWords.collect.toSet)

// Split using a regular expression that extracts words
val wordsWithStopWords: RDD[String] = input.flatMap(x => x.split("\\W+"))
wordsWithStopWords.filter(!broadcastStopWords.value.contains(_))
```

Broadcast variables allow you to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner (in this case as well).

Answer (score 0):

Using subtractByKey:

```
// Creating the RDDs
val input = sc.textFile("../book.txt")
val stopWordsInput = sc.textFile("../stopwords.csv")

// Split using a regular expression that extracts words from input RDD
val wordsWithInput = input.flatMap(x => x.split("\\W+"))


//Converting above RDDs to lowercase
val lowercaseInput = wordsWithInput.map(x => x.toLowerCase())
val lowercaseStopWordsInput = stopWordsInput.map(x => x.toLowerCase())

//Creating a tuple(word, 1) using map for above RDDs
val tupleInput = lowercaseInput.map(x => (x,1))
val tupleStopWordsInput = lowercaseStopWordsInput.map(x => (x,1))

//using subtractByKey
val tupleWords = tupleInput.subtractByKey(tupleStopWordsInput)

//to have only words in RDD
val words = tupleWords.keys
```